# Program white-screening all of a sudden

Tags: electron

I've been working for a few days on an electron application. When I was done working for the day yesterday, the program was working and running just fine. I came in this morning to start working on it again, and now all of a sudden partway through the program it just whitescreens now. I have not changed anything from the time of working on it last (last known working) to current time.

I do not see any errors being logged to the powershell console after running `npm start` (Program does not work packaged either), and when I use inspect element it just says:

> DevTools was disconnected from the page.
>
> Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect.

But it just sits on this white page forever.

This page has quite a lot of code (531 lines), but I am completely unable to pinpoint the problem because there are no errors logged. That said, I began taking pieces out of my code trying to get it to work, and I was able to narrow it down to the code below.

What can I do to fix my application?

This is the code I narrowed it down to, when I comment out this code, the page runs fine.

```
var audio = require('win-audio').speaker;
```

weirdly enough, this is one of the first pieces of code that I had written in this page of the application, and it has worked until just today.

I just found out that if I plug in some speakers, the program no longer whitescreens. But this isn't really a good fix, because this program will be ran on hundreds of computers a day that may or may not have speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE::**

Ok, I think I have fixed it. To try it out:

1. Download my fork at: https://github.com/11AND2/win-audio
2. In your terminal change dir (cd) into the directory e.g. "cd C:\...\win-audio"
3. run command "npm run install" - this rebuilds the module
4. To test it run "node sample.js" and activate/disable your audio devices

If at any point you want to check if the device is alive just run

```
var audio = require('win-audio').speaker;
var _vol_alive = audio.get();
if (_vol_alive === -999) {
   console.log("this device is dead :-(");
}
```

in your application. Please note that I have not changed the API at all so there should be no need to change your application code.

Please give me a heads up if the fix works for you so I can create a pull request for the fix. I am not the creator of this plugin, all my changes are public domain.

---

**DEPRECATED::**

Ok, I have found a fix for you. Would it be ok if:

```
var audio = require('win-audio').speaker;
```

returns -1 if no device is found?

So you could do:

```
if (audio !== -1) {
   audio.set(30);
}
```

Please give me a short heads up and I will post the implementation route.

Comment: That's totally fine.

Comment: I'm getting an error now - `A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.`

Comment: If this happens during "npm run install", is your system able to build c++ addons? If you are on windows have you installed visual studio and python?

Comment: No, it happens after that. It happens when I run my Electron application and get to the page that uses that code. I'm pretty sure it built without issue, as I didn't get any error

Comment: Does it work in a pure node (not electron) app/demo? If yes, it could be that you need to rebuild it for electron. For example in the win-audio package.json you can create a new "scripts" option like: "install_vele": "node-gyp rebuild --target=X.X.X --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" (replace X.X.X with your electron version). Then do a "npm run install_vele".

Comment: I was able to fix it with https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild - however, there was an issue in the `package.json`. "main" was set to "dist/index.js", but once everything was said and done, `index.js` was actually in directory `src`, so I had to change it to `"main": "src/index.js",`

Comment: Good to hear, you can also check https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules if you want to learn more about building native addons for electron. Does it work now eg is the bug fixed?

Comment: Yes it is fixed.